# For $f \in L^1[0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 x^nf(x)dx = 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, then $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

> Prove that if $f \in L^1[0,1]$ is such a function such that for all $n = 0,1,2,\dotsc$,
>
> $$\int_0^1 x^n f(x) \, dx = 0,$$
>
> then $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

Intuitively, I see this to be true, but I am not sure how to prove this.

One approach I considered is the following: using that $f(x)$ and $x^n$ are in $L^1[0,1]$, we can say

$$\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^n f(x) \, dx \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 x^n \right) \left( \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \left( \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \right),
\end{align}$$

and that since the sum is one off from the harmonic series which is divergent, we must have that $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$. However, that is not enough to say that $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere.

My second thought was to use some sort of reasoning of the sort used in complex analysis to say that if the integral involving $x^n$ is zero, we could say something about the number of zeroes of $x^n f(x)$ and use that to somehow say that we must have $f(x) = 0$, but I am not actually sure how that sort of argument could work.

What is the correct perspective here?

Comment: Do you know anything about Fourier analysis? You can easily get from powers of $x$ to exponentials to show that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)e^{-isx}dx=0$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your assumption guarantees that $\int_0^1p(x)f(x)dx=0$ for each polynomial $p$. To see this, let $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^ma_kx^k$ be a polynomial. Then
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1p(x)f(x)dx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^ma_kx^kp(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^ma_k\int_0^1x^kf(x)dx=0.
\end{align*}
Next, fix a smooth function $\varphi$ with compact support in $[0,1]$. Then $\varphi$ can be approximated uniformly by polynomials, $p_n$, say. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1\varphi(x)f(x)dx\right|&\leq\left|\int_0^1[\varphi(x)-p_n(x)]f(x)dx\right|+\left|\int_0^1p_n(x)f(x)dx\right|\\&\leq||\varphi-p_n||_\infty||f||_{L^1([0,1])}\to0
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$. Consequently, this shows that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\varphi(x)f(x)dx=0
\end{align*}
for each test function $\varphi$. Thus, $f=0$ almost everywhere by the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations.

Comment: The convergence is in general not uniform (since the completion of the space of polynomials on $[0, 1]$ under the supremum norm is $C^0([0,1])$, not $L^1([0,1])$). This proof directly works if $f$ is $L^2$, and for general case we need a twist.

Comment: You are right. I will corrected my answer.